# Django 1.9 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, character-encoding

I had this same error while working with latin names and i could solve it defining a *`__unicode`__* function in my model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.field) + " - " + self.field

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.field) + " - " + self.field
```

but this time, even with that function i cant make it work in other model when i try to display them in a select input:

**template.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input_especialidad">Compañero</label>
  {{ puntual_form.employee }} <!-- the error is detected here -->
  <div id="help-error" class="hidden">
    <p class="help-block">Este campo es obligatorio.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="help-info">
    <p class="help-block">Los nombres empiezan por su apellido seguido por los nombres.</p>
    <p class="help-block">Tambien puedes teclear el nombre de tu compañero para buscarlo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
class form_Nom_puntual(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Nom_puntual
        fields = ['employee']
        widgets = {
            'employee': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'puntual_employee'}),
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    num_employee = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Nom_puntual(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employees, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ip_nominator = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

**traceback**

```
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /home/rortega/smce/votaciones/models.py in __str__, line 12

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Aguiñaga F
```

I know that the problem is the **ñ** character, but my DataBase has the character set **utf8** and the collate **utf8_unicode_ci**

Comment: For unicode-related errors, please add either `python2` or `python3` tag, as unicode handling differ a lot between those.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advise.

Comment: Error is not related to the database. It happens in your `__str__` method, which is odd as it is seldom used by Django when `__unicode__` is defined. Do you have the full stack trace, previous levels included?